# How to reshape a tensor with None dimension tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have a tensor of shape `(3, None, 80, 10)` and I want to reshape it to `(3*None, 80, 10)`. I tried with the following lines of code but didn't get the desired shape `(3*None, 80, 10)`, I got a tensor of shape `(None, None, None)`:

```
shape = [tf.shape(node_embed_tmp)[k] for k in range(4)]
Y = tf.reshape(node_embed_tmp, [shape[0]*shape[1], shape[2], shape[3]])
```

Any suggestions, Please!

**EDIT:**

I also tried the following code:

```
shape = [tf.shape(node_embed_tmp)[k] for k in range(4)]
Y=tf.reshape(node_embed_tmp, [-1, shape[2], shape[3]])
```

But I got the shape `(None, None, None)` and the following error: `ValueError: Input size (depth of inputs) must be accessible via shape inference, but saw value None.`

Comment: Are you looking on the model.summary() ? Try to call model with actual data

Comment: ```3*None``` doesn't mean anything. Why would you want that? Do you mean ```(3,80,10)```?

Comment: I am newbie to Tensorflow and I am looking for using LSTM on the above tensor through the following lines of code             `lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(embedding_u_size)
            # init_state = cell.zero_state(None, dtype=tf.float32)
  node_type_embed, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, Y, time_major= True, dtype=tf.float32)` and I think that I cannot use model.summary() in this case It is not a keras layers.

Comment: @Ragnar The 3 dimension means a some category of data and None dimension means the batch_size of each category

Comment: I think what you want is ```(None, 80, 10, 3)```

Comment: @Ragnar The tensor has the shape `(3, None, 80, 10)` and each dimension has its significance in my data.

Answer (score 0):

It is challenging to reshape the Variable dimension tensor,
you can use keras.Input library

```
from tensorflow import keras
tensor_shape = (3, None, 80, 10)
input = keras.Input(shape=((None,) + tensor_shape[1:]), dtype = 'int32')
input.shape
```

Output

```
TensorShape([None, None, None, 80, 10])
```